# What is wrong with this FFMpeg filter string?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
<?php
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.75[logo];[0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih*0.3[video][logo];[video][logo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2;" output.mp4')
```

I'm losing my mind trying to fix this.  It WAS working, until I added the alpha transparency.  Now no matter what I try I seem unable to go back to anything that works, getting

> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x5615d18ba440] No such filter: ''
> Error initializing complex filters
> Invalid argument

every time.  My logs seem to even show that this string DID work once.  It feels like I'm missing something really stupid, please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no terminator after the final filter, so remove the semi-colon after the overlay.

P.S. if you mean to scale the logo with reference to the video, it should be

```
[logo][0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih*0.3[logo][video]
```

Comment: Eurgh, that reminds me of my c++ days, only the opposite!  

Could you tell me how to specify explicit scaling factors?  Let's say my watermark file is 800x600, but I've pre-calculated in PHP that I wish to display it at 400x300 (centered in the frame?)  Thank you!